# How do Jax-WS web-services work? One endpoint per request?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'm trying to understand how Jax-WS web services work but can't find any resources on the specifics of them. By way of example:

I create a very simple Java web service using Jax-WS annotations, like so

```
@WebService(name = "MyService", serviceName = "MyService", portName = "MyServicePort")
public class MyService {

    private int val;

    public MyService() {
        val = 0;
    }

    @WebMethod(action = "setVal")
    public void setVal(@WebParam(name = "arg") int arg) {
        val = arg;
    }

    @WebMethod(action = "getVal")
    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

If I generate a web service from this (using WS-Gen, say), build a client and make the following calls from a single client: `setVal(5)`, `getVal()`, what value will be returned to the client? Why?

What about if client A calls `setVal(5)`, and client B calls `getVal()`, what value will be returned to the client? Why?

Naturally I could build a web-service myself and test it, but I was hoping for an explination to go with the answer. Does Jax-Ws create a new instance of the annotated class for each request? Does it somehow map the same source to the same annotated class instance? Does it just map all requests to a singleton instance of the annotated class? Is there a finite pool of annotated class instances that picked from in some fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web Services are stateless by default because of the underlying HTTP protocol. The server processes each web service request as a new interaction even though it is from the same client

> Normally, a JAX-WS Web service is stateless: that is, none of the
>   local variables and object values that you set in the Web service
>   object are saved from one invocation to the next. Even sequential
>   requests from a single client are treated each as independent,
>   stateless method invocations.
>
> There are Web service use cases where a client may want to save data
>   on the service during one invocation and then use that data during a
>   subsequent invocation. For example, a shopping cart object may be
>   added to by repeated calls to the addToCart web method and then
>   fetched by the getCart web method. In a stateless Web service, the
>   shopping cart object would always be empty, no matter how many
>   addToCart methods were called. But by using HTTP Sessions to maintain
>   state across Web service invocations, the cart may be built up
>   incrementally, and then returned to the client.
>
> Enabling stateful support in a JAX-WS Web service requires a minimal
>   amount of coding on both the client and server.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13734/stateful.htm